# Операции с разными типами данных

Tags: c++, ооп, шаблоны-с++, концепты

Пишу шаблонный класс на плюсах. Если задать разные типы для класса *(Например double для a и int для b)*, то будет ошибка. Вопрос: можно ли этого избежать предусмотрев это в классе или обязательно указывать это в main?

```
//main
#include <iostream>
#include "Rational.h"
using namespace std;


int main()
{
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "Russian");
    cout << "Число а";
    Rational<double> a(9,5);
    a.Print();
    cout << "Число b";
    Rational<int> b(3,10);
    b.Print();
 
    a.Plus(b);       //<---- ошибка (складываю разные типы) 

    system("pause");

    return 0;
}

//h.
#ifndef RATIONAL_H
#define RATIONAL_H
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

template <typename T>
class Rational
{
public:

    Rational()
    {
        p = 0;
        q = 1;

        
    }



    Rational(T p, T q)
    {
        this->p = p;
        this->q = q;


        
    }



    ~Rational()
    {

    }


    void Print()
    {
        cout << " = " << p << "/" << q << endl;
    }


    int GCD(T test_p, T test_q)
    {
        while (test_p != 0 and test_q != 0)
        {
            if (test_p > test_q)
            {
                test_p = test_p % test_q;
            }
            else
            {
                test_q = test_q % test_p;
            }
        }

        return (test_p + test_q);
    }



    Rational Plus(const Rational& arg)
    {
        cout << "Операция сложения:\n" << p << "/" << q << " + " << arg.p << "/" << arg.q;
        T p1, p2, num, denom;

        p1 = p * arg.q;
        p2 = arg.p * q;
        num = p1 + p2;
        denom = arg.q * q;
        int gcd = GCD(num, denom);

        return Show(num / gcd, denom / gcd);

    }



    Rational Show(T test_p, T test_q)
    {
        cout << " = " << test_p << "/" << test_q << endl;

        return *this;
    }

private:
    T p, q;
};

#endif
```

Comment: Можно сделать специализацию шаблона, и в ней определить оператор приведения типа к Rational<double>.

Comment: Избежать *как*? Разрешить такое суммирование или категорически запретить? Вы хотите преобразовывать класс с `int` в класс с `double`? Надо четко определить, что именно вы хотите; сейчас из вопроса непонятно, что вам нужно. И, кстати, мое мнение — рациональные числа с вещественными числителем и знаменателем — вообще нонсенс...

Comment: @Harry Категорически запретить. Надо чтобы тип был обязательно `int`

Comment: **Только** `int`? Тогда не делайте этот класс шаблоном!

Comment: Так ведь это у вас и так запрещено: попытка сложения разных типов приводит к ошибке компиляции.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Как я понимаю, надо, чтоб сам тип шаблона был только целочисленный...

Если только `int` - не надо использовать шаблон...

Если могут быть разные целочисленные типы — ну, например, использовать концепты или иные ухищрения.

Например:

```
template<std::integral T>
class Rational
```

или

```
template<typename T, typename = std::enable_if_t<std::is_integral<T>::value>>
class Rational
```

или

```
template<typename T>
class Rational
{
    static_assert(std::is_integral<T>::value,"Non integral type");
```

Правда, все равно останутся проблемы при суммировании разных типов — здесь вам нужно будет писать преобразование одного типа в другой...

Кроме того, у вас ряд не то чтобы ошибок, но... `GCD` — это же явно статическая функция, например. Или конструктор я бы делал так:

```
Rational(T p = 0, T q = 1):p(p),q(q){}
```

он же — и конструктор по умолчанию...